# How to write tuples and triples in latex?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, logic

How to write like this tuples and triples in latex? `A = (L, l0, G)` and like this `g ∈ G ⊆ L × Ops × L` too? I searched a while but nothing found.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.``

Comment: Like this: `$A=(L, 10, G)$` and `$g\in G\subseteq L \times \mathrm{Ops} \times L$`

Comment: @Sigur how to put this 0 of l0 in below of l?

Comment: @Alex, consider reading some basic introduction on how to typeset in LaTeX. By the way, for subscripts, use underline `I_{0}`.